# Resilience4j Circuit Breaker fallback is called on every request

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, fallback, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

My service uses Spring Cloud Gateway with routes to other services.
I added a route filter like so

```
- name: CircuitBreaker
  args:
    name: circuitBreakerTest
    fallbackUri: forward:/fallback/test
```

my fallback method looks like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
public String testFallback() {
  return "Fallback method called";
}
```

and configured a default Resilience4j Circuit Breaker like this

```
@Bean
public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
  return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
    .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults())
    .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
    .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4)).build()).build());
}
```

Now everytime the specific route with the circuit breaker filter is called, the fallback method gets called as well.
Did i miss something in my configuration?